# VBA click button with no ID

Tags: vba, onclick, click

How can I click without class name, the link with the following element is as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ChooseRange()">Add Range +</a>
```

The complete element before and after it is as follows:

```
<li class="rangeDefault">
    <a href="#" onclick="ChooseRange()">Add Range +</a>
</li>
```

This is the vba code i used but did not work:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("Add Range +").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the querySelector Method of the HTMLDocument object, which will allow you to get the desired element by the onclick attribute...

```
doc.querySelector("[onclick='ChooseRange()']").click
```